# Блокировка окна javafx

Tags: javafx

Во время выполнения дополнительного потока в приложении надо блокировать окно пока доп. поток не закончит выполняться.

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        // выполнение задачи
    });
    thread.start();
```

Как на это время блокировать primaryStage?

Comment: в каком смысле блокировать? может лучше вывести прогресс-бар?

Comment: Чтобы пользователь не мог что-либо изменять (нажимать кнопки, вводить информацию, закрыть окно и т.д.).

Comment: тут лучше будет вывести диалоговое окно с прогресс-баром и при попытке закрыть окно предупреждать, что процесс не завершен и не закрывать это диалоговое окно. диалоговое окно по умолчанию блокирует другие окна.

Comment: Пробовал так,тоже проблема, при вызове нового окна блокируется не только родительское окно, но и все потоки выполняющиеся в нем. Сейчас как вариант у корневой панели устанавливаю свойство  setDisable(true), а потом соответственно разблокирую. Но данный вариант мне не очень нравится.

Comment: Это потому, что вы не используете Task и Worker, а выполняете все в UI потоке. Что является грубым нарушением контракт.

Comment: Если не сложно добавьте ссылку на какой-нибудь пример. Первый раз слышу чтобы диалоговые окна запускали в отдельном потоке, но даже если так и мы блокируем родительское окно, то все потоки в родительском окне тоже будут заблокированы?!

Comment: Все окна работают в ОДНОМ потоке. Это javafx application thread. Откройте javadoc и вы найдёте там много ссылок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Грубый пример на `Dialog`( можно то же самое `Alert` или ещё как-нибудь, вариантов много ):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        StackPane pane = new StackPane( new Text( "Same content" ) );
        Button button = new Button( "Start task" );
        button.setOnAction( e -> {
            createDialog();
        } );
        VBox.setVgrow( pane, Priority.ALWAYS );
        VBox root = new VBox( pane, button );
        root.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 300, 275 ) );
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void createDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        ProgressIndicator indiacator = new ProgressIndicator();
        indiacator.setProgress( ProgressIndicator.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS );

        MyService service = new MyService();
        service.setOnSucceeded( wse -> {
            System.out.println( "good job" );
            dialog.close();
        } );
        service.setOnFailed( wse -> {
            service.getException().printStackTrace();
            dialog.close();
        } );

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent( indiacator );
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add( new ButtonType( "Прервать", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE ) );
        dialog.setResultConverter( dialogButton -> {
            service.cancel();
            return null;
        } );

        service.restart();
        dialog.show();
    }

    private class MyService extends Service<Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
            return new Task<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    //task
                    try {
                        for ( int i = 0; i != 10; i++ ) {
                            System.out.println( "!" );
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep( 500 );
                        }
                    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
    }

}
```